# rendering to the document nested dom nodes

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I was playing around on how rendering html to the document works, mostly for fun and learning. I saw how react, and mostly all vdom/hyperscript implementations recursively renders the nested nodes. Wondered how I can achieve something similar with arrays.

So, if I have an function that returns a render method, that outputs an array.

```
    function Comp() {
        return {
          render: function () {
            return [
              "<div>",
              '  <button name="button-test" type="button">test</button>',
              SubComp(),
              "</div>",
            ];
          },
          postRender: function (dom) {
            dom
              .querySelector("button[name=button-test]")
              .addEventListener("click", function () {
                console.log("haha");
              });
          },
        };
      }


      function SubComp() {
    return {
      render: function () {
        return [
          "<div>",
          '  <button name="button-does-nothing" type="button">nothing</button>',
          "</div>",
        ];
      },
    };
  }
```

In the example above I could ignore the postrender method, call the SubComp().render() method from inside Comp and do:

```
 document.getElementById('someid').innerHTML(Comp().render().flat(Infinity).join(''));
```

And then after perform any dom related stuff. That would nest anything that I throw in. But I also lose the ability to work on each function in case I want to attach dom events specifically for that node or portion of the html, for example.

So my question is, does anyone know how I can achieve this, by having the dom node available for each function. Then I can  perform it's postrender method (or wtv that I want to do with when the node is ready) and only then, nest it into the outer node that it might have.

Again this is more like a exercise and learning so please try not to suggest me libs or frameworks.

PS: turning the array returned into a hyperscript object at runtime also would work for me if anybody knows how.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.

I am thinking that this can be improved maybe with reduce.
This how far I got at the moment, did not do too much test but it seems to work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script>
    function render(component) {
  if (component.preRender) {
    component.preRender();
  }
  var thisComponent = component.render();
  var thisDom = document.createElement('div');
  var children = [];
  thisComponent.forEach(function (c, index) {
    if (typeof c === 'object' && c.hasOwnProperty('render')) {
      children.push(render(c, thisDom.querySelector('div')));
      thisComponent[index] = '<div id="child' + (children.length) + '"></div>';
    }
  });
  var parsedDom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(thisComponent.flat(Infinity).join(''), 'text/html').body.childNodes;
  var length = parsedDom.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    thisDom.appendChild(parsedDom[0]);
  }
  if (component.postRender) {
    component.postRender(thisDom);
  }
  children.forEach(function (child, index) {
    while (child.firstChild) {
      var tchild = child.removeChild(child.firstChild);
      thisDom.querySelector('[id=child' + (index + 1) + ']').parentElement.insertBefore(tchild, thisDom.querySelector('[id=child' + (index + 1) + ']'));
    }
    thisDom.querySelector('[id=child' + (index + 1) + ']').remove();
  });
  return thisDom;
}
    </script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
<script>
  function Component() {
    return {
      render: function () {
        return [
          '  <button name="button-test" type="button">test click me</button>',
          '<div id="test">',
          SubComponent(),
          "</div>",
        ];
      },
      postRender: function (dom) {
        dom
          .querySelector("button[name=button-test]")
          .addEventListener("click", function () {
            console.log("this was added while detached haha");
          });
      },
    };
  }
  function SubComponent() {
    return {
      render: function () {
        return [
          '  <button name="button-does-nothing" type="button">nothing</button>',
          SubSubComp(),
        ];
      },
    };
  }
  function SubSubComp() {
    return {
      render: function () {
        return [
          '  <button name="button-does-nothing-too" type="button">does nothing as well</button>',
        ];
      },
    };
  }
  document.getElementById("app").appendChild(render(Component()));
</script>
```

So if anyone can help to improve the code, also I would accept as an answer.

Another thing, do you guys know how faster is manipulating detached dom? or are there benchmarks for this? I found only for dom attached to the browser.

Comment: You can see I am creating an reference as a id'ed div so I can later replace it the children generated dom before attaching it to the document. 

Did not want that, but just wanted to make it work and then I can figure it out later or some of our folks here can suggest sg more elegant.